# .sample() Returns Different Result with Fixed Random Generator Seed in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, random-seed

I am new to Spark, and I am working on some data wrangling. I have an issue when doing random row selection from an RDD table in Spark.

In order to make sure that the row I am selecting from the RDD table be the same every time (this is easier for me to check if the later table join is correct or not), I pre-specify the random see generator. I use `.sample()`. Here is the code:

`val distinct_id = rddtable.select("id").distinct().sample(false, .00008, seed = 1453)`

The random generator seed is set to be 1453. However,

`distinct_id.show()`

will show different result every time I run it.

This is very strange in terms of my experience in R and Python. In R and Python, if I pre-specify the seed, the random generator should give me the same results all the time.

Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: I suspect this is because Spark is recalculating from lazy evaluation every time you call show(). If you cache after calling sample() you should get the same result each time.

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting the distinct id rdd before sampling. It could happen that the order of id is different between each run, hence the different sampling result.